# Can someone explain the Shiver Me Timbers hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

The explanation is like so:

> ### Shiver Me Timbers
>
> provide the highest scoring answer that outscores an accepted answer with a score of 3 or more by 2x or more

So does that mean:

I need an answer that has 3 or more upvotes that is higher in votes than the accepted answer **or** outscore the accepted answer by 2x or more

### or does it mean:

I need an answer that has 3 or more upvotes that is higher in votes than the accepted answer **and** outscore the accepted answer by 2x or more

## ?

Comment: It is a secret hat! Don't spoil it.

Comment: @AustinHenley [it's no secret](http://winterba.sh/shiver-me-timbers)

Comment: Yea, it *was* a secret...

Comment: Regarding secret hats, I have it on good authority that there are hats thought to be so unattainable that they weren't worth weighing down the sprite. Then again, I talk to rocks, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: @TinyTimPost hehe there are people that have the pirate hat :-P

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Oh, you meant _that_ pirate hat. Sorry.

Comment: @TinyTimPost  ooooo you think you are so funny :-P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's like the Populist badge; check that:

- there is an accepted answer
- the accepted answer has a score of three or more
- your answer has a score at least 2x greater than that answer
- your answer has the highest score out of all answers

Answer (score 1):

> **Shiver Me Timbers**
>
> provide the highest scoring answer that outscores an accepted answer with a score of 3 or more by 2x or more

When a question has an accepted answer that is **not yours** with a score of atleast 3. You have to have an answer thats score is twice as much as the accepted answer **and** is the highest scored answer.

Answer (score 0):

provide the **highest scoring** answer that *outscores* an (**accepted answer with a score of 3** or more) **by 2x** or more

It looks like if a question has an answer with a score of 3, you get this badge by posting an answer with a score of six, and only if there are no even yet better answers

Answer (score 0):

You need to answer a question where the accepted answer has at least a score of 3, and your answer is the one with the highest score, that is at least twice the score of the accepted answer.